# How to stop a label from moving back input field?

Tags: html, css

I currently have a input field that lets you type your Full name. I also have a label that moves to the top once you click into the input field. However, once you type something in the input field, the label moves back to the same spot and overlaps the text.

Is there a way to make it so that the label will stay at the top if there is text in the input field? My code is below.

**Contact.jsx:**

```
<form id='contact-form'>
   <input className='contact-form-input' id='contact-full-name' placeholder='Full Name' type='text' name='name' required/>
   <label for='name' className='contact-form-label'>Full Name</label>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
#contact-form{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.contact-form-input{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 1;
}
.contact-form-label{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 5px;
    left: 4px;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: .2s;
    z-index: 0;
}
#contact-full-name::placeholder{
    opacity: 1;
    color: transparent;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.contact-form-input:focus{
    color: brown;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}
.contact-form-input:focus + .contact-form-label{
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: .2s;
}
```

Comment: You can use the pseudo class `:placeholder-shown`

Comment: Thank you, I just tried it and it worked. I also found the pseudo class :valid

Comment: the `:valid` pseudo class is more of a hack for your specific scenario where you're allowing any input. But `:placeholder-shown` is the correct pseudo class to use for this, as it will also work when there is a possibility of invalid inputs.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research I found the pseudo class of **:valid**.

When using `.contact-form-input:valid + .contact-form-label` I am able to modify the label state after text is in the input field.